# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props') in my react native project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to send a piece of data using a useState from screen A to screen B in my react native project but keep getting an error when trying to retrieve the data on the second screen using navigation.getParam('orchardName')

**newOrchar_1.js**

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
  Dimensions,
  StatusBar,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    ScrollView
} from "react-native";
import { Block, Checkbox, Text, theme } from "galio-framework";

import { Button, Icon, Input } from "../components";
import { Images, argonTheme } from "../constants";
import {  useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native' // <-- import useNavigation hook


const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("screen");



const  newOrchard = () => {     
    
    
    

    const [orchardName, setOrchardName] = useState();
    const navigation = useNavigation() // <-- add this line
    
    
    return (
        
        <ScrollView>
      <Block flex middle>
        <StatusBar hidden />
        <ImageBackground
          source={Images.RegisterBackground}
          style={{ width, height, zIndex: 1 }}
        >
          <Block flex middle>

        <Block flex space="between" style={styles.padded}>
          <Block flex space="around" style={{ zIndex: 2 }}>
                <Block style={styles.title}>
                  <Block>
                    <Text color="black" size={40}>
              Fruitminder
                    </Text>
          </Block>
          <Block style={styles.subTitle}>
                    <Text color="black" size={16}>
              Lets name your orchard and give it a picture
                    </Text>
                  </Block>
        </Block>
        </Block>
    
        
            <Block style={styles.registerContainer}>
          
        
                <Block flex center>
                  <KeyboardAvoidingView
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    behavior="padding"
                    enabled
                    >
            
            <Block width={width * 0.8} style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
              <Block style={styles.subTitle}>
            <Text color="black" size={16}>
              What is the name of your Orchard?
            </Text>
                      </Block>
                      <Input
                        borderless
                        placeholder="Name of Orchard"
                        iconContent={
                <Icon
                      size={16}
                      color={argonTheme.COLORS.ICON}
                      name="pencil"
                      family="ArgonExtra"
                      style={styles.inputIcons}
                      />
                }
            onChangeText={orchardName => setOrchardName(orchardName)}
            defaultValue={orchardName}
                />
                    </Block>

            <Block width={width * 0.8} style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
              <Block style={styles.subTitle}>
            <Text color="black" size={16}>
              Upload a Photo or Logo of your Orchard
            </Text>
                      </Block>
                      <Input
                        borderless
                        placeholder="Upload Photo or Logo"
                        iconContent={
                <Icon
                      size={16}
                      color={argonTheme.COLORS.ICON}
                      name="image"
                      family="ArgonExtra"
                      style={styles.inputIcons}
                      />
                }
                />
                    </Block>

            
         
                    <Block row  width={width * 0.75} style={{justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                      <Button color="secondary" style={styles.createButton}
                  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("prev")}
                  >
                        <Text bold size={14} color={argonTheme.COLORS.BLACK}>
                          Previous Step
                        </Text>
                      </Button>
              <Button color="secondary" style={styles.createButton}
                  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("next", {orchName: orchardName})}
                  >
                        <Text bold size={14} color={argonTheme.COLORS.BLACK}>
                          Next Step
                        </Text>
                      </Button>
                    </Block>

            
                  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                </Block>
              </Block>
            </Block>
          </Block>
        </ImageBackground>
        </Block>
        </ScrollView>
    );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  registerContainer: {
    width: width * 0.9,
    height: height * 0.78,
    backgroundColor: "#F4F5F7",
    borderRadius: 4,
    shadowColor: argonTheme.COLORS.BLACK,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 4
    },
    shadowRadius: 8,
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    elevation: 1,
    overflow: "hidden"
  },
  socialConnect: {
    backgroundColor: argonTheme.COLORS.WHITE,
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    borderColor: "#8898AA"
  },
  socialButtons: {
    width: 120,
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    shadowColor: argonTheme.COLORS.BLACK,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 4
    },
    shadowRadius: 8,
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    elevation: 1
  },
  socialTextButtons: {
    color: argonTheme.COLORS.PRIMARY,
    fontWeight: "800",
    fontSize: 14
  },
  inputIcons: {
    marginRight: 12
  },
  passwordCheck: {
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingTop: 13,
    paddingBottom: 30
  },
  createButton: {
    width: "40%",
    marginTop: 25
  },
  title: {
      marginTop:5
  },
  subTitle: {
      marginTop: 5
  },
  padded: {
      paddingHorizontal: theme.SIZES.BASE *2,
      position: "relative",
      bottom: theme.SIZES.BASE,
      zIndex: 2,
  }
  
});

export default newOrchard;
```

**newOrchard_2.js**

```
mport React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
  Dimensions,
  StatusBar,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    ScrollView
} from "react-native";
import { Block, Checkbox, Text, theme } from "galio-framework";

import { Button, Icon, Input } from "../components";
import { Images, argonTheme } from "../constants";
import {  useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native' // <-- import useNavigation hook


const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("screen");

const  newOrchard  = () => {
   
    const { navigation } = useNavigation(); // <-- add this line
    const orchardName = this.props.navigation.getParam('orchardName');
    console.log(orchardName)
    
    
    return (
        <ScrollView>
      <Block flex middle>
        <StatusBar hidden />
        <ImageBackground
          source={Images.RegisterBackground}
          style={{ width, height, zIndex: 1 }}
        >
          <Block flex middle>

        <Block flex space="between" style={styles.padded}>
          <Block flex space="around" style={{ zIndex: 2 }}>
                <Block style={styles.title}>
                  <Block>
                    <Text color="black" size={40}>
              Fruitminder
                    </Text>
          </Block>
          <Block style={styles.subTitle}>
                    <Text color="black" size={16}>
              Lets grab some details for your orchard! 
                    </Text>
                  </Block>
        </Block>
          </Block>
        
            <Block style={styles.registerContainer}>
          
        
                <Block flex center>
                  <KeyboardAvoidingView
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    behavior="padding"
                    enabled
                    >
            
            <Block width={width * 0.8} style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
              <Block style={styles.subTitle}>
            <Text color="black" size={16}>
             Where is your orchard located? 
            </Text>
                      </Block>

              <Input
                        borderless
                        placeholder="Find your farm via GPS Location"
                        iconContent={
                <Icon
                      size={16}
                      color={argonTheme.COLORS.ICON}
                      name="pencil"
                      family="ArgonExtra"
                      style={styles.inputIcons}
                      />
                }
                />
              <Input
                        borderless
                        placeholder="Manually Enter Details "
                        iconContent={
                <Icon
                      size={16}
                      color={argonTheme.COLORS.ICON}
                      name="pencil"
                      family="ArgonExtra"
                      style={styles.inputIcons}
                      />
                }
                />
              
                    </Block>

          
            
         
                    <Block row  width={width * 0.75} style={{justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                      <Button color="secondary" style={styles.createButton}
                  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("prev")}
                  >
                        <Text bold size={14} color={argonTheme.COLORS.BLACK}>
                          Previous Step
                        </Text>
                      </Button>
              <Button color="secondary" style={styles.createButton}
                  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("next")}
                  >
                        <Text bold size={14} color={argonTheme.COLORS.BLACK}>
                          Next Step
                        </Text>
                      </Button>
                    </Block>

            
                  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                </Block>
              </Block>
            </Block>
          </Block>
        </ImageBackground>
        </Block>
        </ScrollView>
    );
  
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  registerContainer: {
    width: width * 0.9,
    height: height * 0.78,
    backgroundColor: "#F4F5F7",
    borderRadius: 4,
    shadowColor: argonTheme.COLORS.BLACK,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 4
    },
    shadowRadius: 8,
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    elevation: 1,
    overflow: "hidden"
  },
  socialConnect: {
    backgroundColor: argonTheme.COLORS.WHITE,
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    borderColor: "#8898AA"
  },
  socialButtons: {
    width: 120,
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    shadowColor: argonTheme.COLORS.BLACK,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 4
    },
    shadowRadius: 8,
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    elevation: 1
  },
  socialTextButtons: {
    color: argonTheme.COLORS.PRIMARY,
    fontWeight: "800",
    fontSize: 14
  },
  inputIcons: {
    marginRight: 12
  },
  passwordCheck: {
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingTop: 13,
    paddingBottom: 30
  },
  createButton: {
    width: "40%",
    marginTop: 25
  },
  title: {
      marginTop:5
  },
  subTitle: {
      marginTop: 5
  },
  padded: {
      paddingHorizontal: theme.SIZES.BASE *2,
      position: "relative",
      bottom: theme.SIZES.BASE,
      zIndex: 2,
  }
  
});

export default newOrchard;
```

**screens.js** : meant to be the navigation controller

```
import React from "react";
import { Easing, Animated, Dimensions } from "react-native";

import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

import { Block } from "galio-framework";

// screens
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import Onboarding from "../screens/Onboarding";
import OnboardingPick from "../screens/OnboardingPick"
import Pro from "../screens/Pro";
import Profile from "../screens/Profile";
import Register from "../screens/Register";
import Elements from "../screens/Elements";
import Articles from "../screens/Articles";
import newAccount_1 from "../screens/newAccount_1"
import newAccount_2 from "../screens/newAccount_2"
import todoTest from "../screens/todoTest"
import newOrchard_1 from "../screens/newOrchard_1"
import newOrchard_2 from "../screens/newOrchard_2"
import joinOrchard_1 from "../screens/joinOrchard_1"
import addressIn from "../screens/manualAddressInput"
import treeSelect from "../screens/fruitTreeSelection"
import orchRowDetails from "../screens/orchRowDetails"
import newOrchDetails from "../screens/newOrchDetails"

// drawer
import CustomDrawerContent from "./Menu";

// header for screens
import { Icon, Header } from "../components";
import { argonTheme, tabs } from "../constants";

const { width } = Dimensions.get("screen");

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function ElementsStack(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="screen">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Elements"
        component={Elements}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Header title="Elements" navigation={navigation} scene={scene} />
          ),
          cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "blue" }
        }}
      />
            <Stack.Screen
        name="Pro"
        component={Pro}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Header
              title=""
              back
              white
              transparent
              navigation={navigation}
              scene={scene}
            />
          ),
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function ArticlesStack(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="screen">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Articles"
        component={Articles}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Header title="Articles" navigation={navigation} scene={scene} />
          ),
          cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#F8F9FE" }
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Pro"
        component={Pro}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Header
              title=""
              back
              white
              transparent
              navigation={navigation}
              scene={scene}
            />
          ),
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function ProfileStack(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Profile" mode="card" headerMode="screen">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Header
              transparent
              white
              title="Profile"
              navigation={navigation}
              scene={scene}
            />
          ),
          cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF" },
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
      />
            <Stack.Screen
        name="Pro"
        component={Pro}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Header
              title=""
              back
              white
              transparent
              navigation={navigation}
              scene={scene}
            />
          ),
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function HomeStack(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="screen">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Header
              title="Home"
              search
              options
              navigation={navigation}
              scene={scene}
            />
          ),
          cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#F8F9FE" }
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Pro"
        component={Pro}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Header
              title=""
              back
              white
              transparent
              navigation={navigation}
              scene={scene}
            />
          ),
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}





export default function OnboardingStack(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="none">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Onboarding"
        component={Onboarding}
        option={{
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
    />
    
    <Stack.Screen name="App" component={AppStack} />
    <Stack.Screen name="OnboardingPick" component={OnboardingPickStack} />
    
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}


function OnboardingPickStack(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="none">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="OnboardingPick"
        component={OnboardingPick}
        option={{
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
    />
    
    <Stack.Screen name="App" component={AppStack} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginPage} />
    <Stack.Screen name="newUser" component={CreateNewAccount_1} />
    <Stack.Screen name="todoTest" component={todoTest} />
      
    
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}


function LoginPage(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="none">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="login"
        component={Register}
        option={{
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
    />
      
      <Stack.Screen name="joinOrchard" component={JoinOrchard_1} />
      
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function JoinOrchard_1(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="none">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="joinOrchard_1"
        component={joinOrchard_1}
        option={{
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
    />
      
      
      <Stack.Screen name="prev" component={LoginPage} />
      <Stack.Screen name="next" component={Home} />
    
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function CreateNewAccount_1(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="none">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="newUser_1"
        component={newAccount_1}
        option={{
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
    />
      
      
      <Stack.Screen name="prev" component={OnboardingPickStack} />
      <Stack.Screen name="next" component={CreateNewAccount_2} />
    
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function CreateNewAccount_2(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="none">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="newUser_2"
        component={newAccount_2}
        option={{
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
    />
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginPage} />
      <Stack.Screen name="newOrchard" component={CreateNewOrchard_1} />
      <Stack.Screen name="prev" component={CreateNewAccount_1} />
      <Stack.Screen name="next" component={CreateNewOrchard_1} />
    
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}


function CreateNewOrchard_1(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="none">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="newOrchard"
        component={newOrchard_1}
        option={{
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
    />
      <Stack.Screen name="prev" component={CreateNewAccount_2} />
      <Stack.Screen name="next" component={CreateNewOrchard_2} />
    
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}


function CreateNewOrchard_2(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="none">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="newOrchard_2"
        component={newOrchard_2}
        option={{
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
    />
      <Stack.Screen name="prev" component={CreateNewOrchard_1} />
      <Stack.Screen name="next" component={ManualAddress} />
    
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function ManualAddress(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="none">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="enterAddress"
        component={addressIn}
        option={{
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
    />
      <Stack.Screen name="prev" component={CreateNewOrchard_2} />
      <Stack.Screen name="next" component={TreeFruitSelect} />
    
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function TreeFruitSelect(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="none">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="selectTreeType"
        component={treeSelect}
        option={{
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
    />
      <Stack.Screen name="prev" component={ManualAddress} />
      <Stack.Screen name="next" component={OrchRowDetails} />
    
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function OrchRowDetails(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="none">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="orchRowDetails"
        component={orchRowDetails}
        option={{
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
    />
      <Stack.Screen name="prev" component={TreeFruitSelect} />
      <Stack.Screen name="next" component={OrchardDetails} />
    
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function OrchardDetails(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="none">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="orchardDetails"
        component={newOrchDetails}
        option={{
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
    />
      <Stack.Screen name="prev" component={orchRowDetails} />
      <Stack.Screen name="next" component={Home} />
    
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}






function AppStack(props) {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
      drawerStyle={{
        backgroundColor: "white",
        width: width * 0.8
      }}
      drawerContentOptions={{
        activeTintcolor: "white",
        inactiveTintColor: "#000",
        activeBackgroundColor: "transparent",
        itemStyle: {
          width: width * 0.75,
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
          paddingVertical: 16,
          paddingHorizonal: 12,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          overflow: "hidden"
        },
        labelStyle: {
          fontSize: 18,
          marginLeft: 12,
          fontWeight: "normal"
        }
      }}
      initialRouteName="Home"
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStack} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Account" component={Register} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Elements" component={ElementsStack} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Articles" component={ArticlesStack} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

please help im confused and tired, just a direction would be helpful

Comment: Hey mate, you are posting some super long script. Can you please point out which line the error is coming from if possible? Or possibly make the scripts minimal?

Comment: You're using function components, so props are not on `this.` They are merely an argument that you can destructure

Answer (score 0):

Update this line:
   `const orchardName = this.props.navigation.getParam('orchardName');` to

`const orchardName = navigation.getParam('orchardName');`